# Crash occurs in mshtml when trying to print the contents of a WebBrowser(ActiveX Control), in MFC Applications using ExecWB

Tags: webbrowser-control

The crash occurs in mshtml when we print the contents of a WebBrowser(ActiveX Control), in MFC Applications.

1) The print dialog is not opening.

For printing from webbrowser, we call the below function
ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, NULL, NULL);

2) The crash starts from preview.js (CPrintDoc_RectComplete method) of ieframe.dll.
3) It is crashing in mshtml, "mshtml!Tree::CIE9DocumentLayout::HandleLayoutBuilderError+0xc6"
4) It is giving "Break instruction exception - code 80000003" .

**Could you please let us know if there is any hotfix available for this callstack**.

The call stack of the crashing thread is

00 000000ea`2e697dc0 00007ffb`483c4097 mshtml!Tree::CIE9DocumentLayout::HandleLayoutBuilderError+0xc6
01 000000ea`2e697e00 00007ffb`47cea9fc mshtml!CMarkupPageLayout::CalcPageLayoutSize+0xa09bcf
02 000000ea`2e697f90 00007ffb`489a6b86 mshtml!CMarkupPageLayout::CalcTopLayoutSizeWithDefault+0x1c
03 000000ea`2e697fc0 00007ffb`47b13a7f mshtml!CContainerLayout::CalcSizeVirtual+0x166
04 000000ea`2e6980c0 00007ffb`4806969e mshtml!CLayout::CalcSize+0x247
05 000000ea`2e698270 00007ffb`480694a8 mshtml!CFlowLayout::MeasureSite+0x42b
06 000000ea`2e6983f0 00007ffb`4806936f mshtml!CFlowLayout::GetSiteWidth+0x123
07 000000ea`2e6984a0 00007ffb`48069959 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::GetSiteWidth+0xaf
08 000000ea`2e698520 00007ffb`4806b97b mshtml!CLineServices::VerticalAlignOneObjectFast+0x443
09 000000ea`2e6985f0 00007ffb`4806ea8a mshtml!CLineServices::VerticalAlignObjectsFast+0x2da
0a 000000ea`2e698730 00007ffb`483648f0 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::Measure+0x3c6
0b 000000ea`2e6987c0 00007ffb`48273b4d mshtml!CLSMeasurer::MeasureLine+0x3c
0c 000000ea`2e698810 00007ffb`4806b01f mshtml!CRecalcLinePtr::MeasureLine+0x2a6
0d 000000ea`2e698980 00007ffb`4806e3ea mshtml!CDisplay::RecalcLinesWithMeasurer+0x2f2
0e 000000ea`2e698ae0 00007ffb`4806d555 mshtml!CDisplay::RecalcLines+0x6a
0f 000000ea`2e698d20 00007ffb`48057c51 mshtml!CDisplay::RecalcView+0x54
10 000000ea`2e698d60 00007ffb`4803af3d mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcTextSize+0x303
11 000000ea`2e698ed0 00007ffb`4805a85d mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcSizeCoreCompat+0x4a9
12 000000ea`2e699440 00007ffb`47b13a7f mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcSizeVirtual+0x89
13 000000ea`2e6994d0 00007ffb`4806969e mshtml!CLayout::CalcSize+0x247
14 000000ea`2e699680 00007ffb`480694a8 mshtml!CFlowLayout::MeasureSite+0x42b
15 000000ea`2e699800 00007ffb`4806936f mshtml!CFlowLayout::GetSiteWidth+0x123
16 000000ea`2e6998b0 00007ffb`48071555 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::GetSiteWidth+0xaf
17 000000ea`2e699930 00007ffb`511539fe mshtml!CEmbeddedILSObj::Fmt+0x261
18 000000ea`2e699a50 00007ffb`51154acf msls31!ProcessOneRun+0x2f1
19 000000ea`2e699ba0 00007ffb`511544fb msls31!FetchAppendEscCore+0x11f
1a 000000ea`2e699ca0 00007ffb`511543bf msls31!FiniFormatGeneralCase+0x11b
1b 000000ea`2e699d70 00007ffb`51153bef msls31!CreateLineCore+0x837
1c 000000ea`2e699f10 00007ffb`4806e2e7 msls31!LsCreateLine+0x11f
1d 000000ea`2e699fa0 00007ffb`480727c9 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::LSDoCreateLine+0x1c3
1e 000000ea`2e69a170 00007ffb`4806ebf8 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::LSMeasure+0x79
1f 000000ea`2e69a290 00007ffb`483648f0 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::Measure+0x160
20 000000ea`2e69a320 00007ffb`48273b4d mshtml!CLSMeasurer::MeasureLine+0x3c
21 000000ea`2e69a370 00007ffb`4806b01f mshtml!CRecalcLinePtr::MeasureLine+0x2a6
22 000000ea`2e69a4e0 00007ffb`4806e3ea mshtml!CDisplay::RecalcLinesWithMeasurer+0x2f2
23 000000ea`2e69a640 00007ffb`4806d555 mshtml!CDisplay::RecalcLines+0x6a
24 000000ea`2e69a880 00007ffb`48057c51 mshtml!CDisplay::RecalcView+0x54
25 000000ea`2e69a8c0 00007ffb`4803af3d mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcTextSize+0x303
26 000000ea`2e69aa30 00007ffb`4805a85d mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcSizeCoreCompat+0x4a9
27 000000ea`2e69afa0 00007ffb`47b13a7f mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcSizeVirtual+0x89
28 000000ea`2e69b030 00007ffb`4806969e mshtml!CLayout::CalcSize+0x247
29 000000ea`2e69b1e0 00007ffb`480694a8 mshtml!CFlowLayout::MeasureSite+0x42b
2a 000000ea`2e69b360 00007ffb`4806936f mshtml!CFlowLayout::GetSiteWidth+0x123
2b 000000ea`2e69b410 00007ffb`48069959 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::GetSiteWidth+0xaf
2c 000000ea`2e69b490 00007ffb`4806b97b mshtml!CLineServices::VerticalAlignOneObjectFast+0x443
2d 000000ea`2e69b560 00007ffb`4806ea8a mshtml!CLineServices::VerticalAlignObjectsFast+0x2da
2e 000000ea`2e69b6a0 00007ffb`483648f0 mshtml!CLSMeasurer::Measure+0x3c6
2f 000000ea`2e69b730 00007ffb`48273b4d mshtml!CLSMeasurer::MeasureLine+0x3c
30 000000ea`2e69b780 00007ffb`48078d35 mshtml!CRecalcLinePtr::MeasureLine+0x2a6
31 000000ea`2e69b8f0 00007ffb`48065115 mshtml!CDisplay::RecalcLines+0x51f
32 000000ea`2e69c4a0 00007ffb`4807ea6c mshtml!CDisplay::UpdateView+0x1cc
33 000000ea`2e69c670 00007ffb`48059fde mshtml!CFlowLayout::CommitChanges+0xcb
34 000000ea`2e69c770 00007ffb`4803af3d mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcTextSize+0x51c
35 000000ea`2e69c8e0 00007ffb`4805a85d mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcSizeCoreCompat+0x4a9
36 000000ea`2e69ce50 00007ffb`47b13a7f mshtml!CFlowLayout::CalcSizeVirtual+0x89
37 000000ea`2e69cee0 00007ffb`48059e0c mshtml!CLayout::CalcSize+0x247
38 000000ea`2e69d090 00007ffb`480547b7 mshtml!CFlowLayout::DoLayout+0x461
39 000000ea`2e69d200 00007ffb`4797eea9 mshtml!CView::ExecuteLayoutTasks+0xe3
3a 000000ea`2e69d290 00007ffb`4820e9da mshtml!CView::EnsureView+0x43f
3b 000000ea`2e69d370 00007ffb`48356a72 mshtml!CElement::EnsureRecalcNotify+0xa4
3c 000000ea`2e69d3b0 00007ffb`47d095ff mshtml!CElement::EnsureRecalcNotify+0x1e
3d 000000ea`2e69d3f0 00007ffb`47d04046 mshtml!CDisplayPointer::MoveToMarkupPointer+0xaf
3e 000000ea`2e69d460 00007ffb`47d0446a mshtml!CSelectionManager::CreateTrackerForContext+0x19e
3f 000000ea`2e69d500 00007ffb`47d0434b mshtml!CSelectionManager::SetEditContext+0xe6
40 000000ea`2e69d580 00007ffb`47d04e65 mshtml!CSelectionManager::SetEditContextFromElement+0x18b
41 000000ea`2e69d670 00007ffb`47d07764 mshtml!CSelectionManager::SetInitialEditContext+0x45
42 000000ea`2e69d6b0 00007ffb`47d086bc mshtml!CSelectionManager::Initialize+0x2a8
43 000000ea`2e69d6e0 00007ffb`47a45272 mshtml!CHTMLEditor::Initialize+0x15c
44 000000ea`2e69d760 00007ffb`47cefa20 mshtml!CDoc::GetHTMLEditor+0x11a
45 000000ea`2e69d7a0 00007ffb`47c43116 mshtml!CElement::InjectInternal+0x807
46 000000ea`2e69d960 00007ffb`47cc5b29 mshtml!CElement::InjectTextOrHTML+0x38d
47 000000ea`2e69da40 00007ffb`47d4fc7d mshtml!CElement::put_innerText+0x29
48 000000ea`2e69da80 00007ffb`47c48429 mshtml!GS_BSTR+0x12b
49 000000ea`2e69daf0 00007ffb`47cdfed0 mshtml!CBase::ContextInvokeEx+0x658
4a 000000ea`2e69dc10 00007ffb`4820d0bd mshtml!CElement::VersionedInvokeEx+0xb7
4b 000000ea`2e69dcc0 00007ffb`465fa1e4 mshtml!CBase::PrivateInvokeEx+0x179
4c 000000ea`2e69dd40 00007ffb`466df12e jscript9!HostDispatch::CallInvokeEx+0x1b6
4d 000000ea`2e69de10 00007ffb`466df05b jscript9!HostDispatch::PutValueByDispId+0xb6
4e 000000ea`2e69ded0 00007ffb`466df00f jscript9!HostDispatch::PutValue+0x37
4f 000000ea`2e69df10 00007ffb`46734757 jscript9!HostDispatch::SetPropertyCore+0x6a
50 000000ea`2e69df40 00007ffb`4656420c jscript9!Js::JavascriptOperators::OP_SetProperty+0x2f8
51 000000ea`2e69dfd0 00007ffb`465644a2 jscript9!Js::JavascriptOperators::PatchPutValueNoFastPath+0x80
52 000000ea`2e69e050 00007ffb`4650e240 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x5553
53 000000ea`2e69e390 000000ea`217d0ddb jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x386
54 000000ea`2e69e680 00007ffb`46509eb3 js!CPrintDoc_RectComplete [res://ieframe.dll/preview.js @ 2660,1]
55 000000ea`2e69e6b0 00007ffb`4672ae52 jscript9!amd64_CallFunction+0x93
56 000000ea`2e69e710 00007ffb`4650e240 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1071
57 000000ea`2e69ea50 000000ea`217d0dfb jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x386
58 000000ea`2e69ec90 00007ffb`46509eb3 js!OnRectCompleteNext [res://ieframe.dll/preview.js @ 742,1]
59 000000ea`2e69ecc0 00007ffb`4672ae52 jscript9!amd64_CallFunction+0x93
5a 000000ea`2e69ed30 00007ffb`4650e240 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::Process+0x1071
5b 000000ea`2e69f070 000000ea`217d0de3 jscript9!Js::InterpreterStackFrame::InterpreterThunk<1>+0x386
5c 000000ea`2e69f2e0 00007ffb`46509eb3 js!anonymous [Unknown script code @ 1,1]
5d 000000ea`2e69f310 00007ffb`46509af1 jscript9!amd64_CallFunction+0x93
5e 000000ea`2e69f360 00007ffb`46509cfe jscript9!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallFunction<1>+0x6d
5f 000000ea`2e69f3a0 00007ffb`46509dff jscript9!Js::JavascriptFunction::CallRootFunction+0x110
60 000000ea`2e69f480 00007ffb`46509d58 jscript9!ScriptSite::CallRootFunction+0x63
61 000000ea`2e69f4e0 00007ffb`46623c42 jscript9!ScriptSite::Execute+0x122
62 000000ea`2e69f570 00007ffb`46658594 jscript9!JavascriptDispatch::InvokeOnSelf+0x102
63 000000ea`2e69f5f0 00007ffb`466586ab jscript9!JavascriptDispatch::InvokeEx+0x1e4
64 000000ea`2e69f700 00007ffb`480d43a9 jscript9!JavascriptDispatch::Invoke+0x7b
65 000000ea`2e69f750 00007ffb`47c84e73 mshtml!CWindow::ExecuteCallbackScript+0x144
66 000000ea`2e69f8d0 00007ffb`4797e57e mshtml!CWindow::FireTimeOut+0x295
67 000000ea`2e69f960 00007ffb`486236a1 mshtml!CPaintBeat::ProcessTimers+0x327
68 000000ea`2e69fa00 00007ffb`47a45ee9 mshtml!CPaintBeat::OnWMTimer+0x61
69 000000ea`2e69fa30 00007ffb`4796e166 mshtml!FormsOnTimer+0x9f
6a 000000ea`2e69fa80 00007ffb`7ad324fd mshtml!GlobalWndProc+0x1c6
6b 000000ea`2e69fb00 00007ffb`7ad32357 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x149
6c 000000ea`2e69fbd0 00007ffb`48667b84 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1a7
6d 000000ea`2e69fc50 00007ffb`785513f2 mshtml!ModelessThreadProc+0x1c4
6e 000000ea`2e69fce0 00007ffb`7aec54f4 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
6f 000000ea`2e69fd10 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34